# Buildozer fail building apk

Tags: python, build, kivy, apk, buildozer

I am trying to build an APK using the Kivy framework. When I try to build the app, i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more
# Command failed: /home/kolterdyx/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/parrot:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1079,unix/parrot:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1079'
#     WINDOWID = '79691783'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'lightdm-xsession'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1120'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     MATE_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     PWD = '/media/kolterdyx/Seagate/Files/Programming/AppDev'
#     LOGNAME = 'kolterdyx'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'lightdm-xsession'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/kolterdyx/.Xauthority'
#     XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/lightdm/data/kolterdyx'
#     GDM_LANG = 'es_ES.utf8'
#     HOME = '/home/kolterdyx'
#     LANG = 'es_ES.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'MATE'
#     VTE_VERSION = '5803'
#     XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING = '0'
#     USER = 'kolterdyx'
#     DISPLAY = ':0.0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     XDG_VTNR = '7'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = '2'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR = '0'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/mate:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/'
#     PATH = '/home/kolterdyx/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/kolterdyx/.local/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/sandbox/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/share/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/kolterdyx/.local/bin/'
#     GDMSESSION = 'lightdm-xsession'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     QT_SCALE_FACTOR = '1'
#     _ = '/home/kolterdyx/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/kolterdyx'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Ive tried two commands:

```
buildozer -v android debug
```

and

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

I have installed python3.8 and 3.7, and I am aware that Kivy hasn't released a wheel for 3.8 yet. Anyways I have done everything I could to use just python 3.7 to build this app, but I still get the error.
I can't work out what is going wrong and I can't find any alternative for Buildozer

I was told to use OpenJDK8 and It worked a little bit further, but then I got this error back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/media/kolterdyx/Seagate/Files/Programming/AppDev/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1199, in <module>
    main()
  File "/media/kolterdyx/Seagate/Files/Programming/AppDev/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/media/kolterdyx/Seagate/Files/Programming/AppDev/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 671, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/media/kolterdyx/Seagate/Files/Programming/AppDev/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 155, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/media/kolterdyx/Seagate/Files/Programming/AppDev/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 206, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/media/kolterdyx/Seagate/Files/Programming/AppDev/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 566, in build_recipes
    recipe.prepare_build_dir(arch.arch)
  File "/media/kolterdyx/Seagate/Files/Programming/AppDev/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 605, in prepare_build_dir
    self.unpack(arch)
  File "/media/kolterdyx/Seagate/Files/Programming/AppDev/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 468, in unpack
    sh.tar('xf', extraction_filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.13.1-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.13.1-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 793, in __init__
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.13.1-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 849, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.13.1-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 877, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/tar xf /media/kolterdyx/Seagate/Files/Programming/AppDev/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/sdl2_image/SDL2_image-2.0.4.tar.gz

  STDOUT:


  STDERR:
/usr/bin/tar: SDL2_image-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/webp.framework/Resources: No se puede crear el enlace simbólico a «Versions/Current/Resources»: Función no implementada
/usr/bin/tar: SDL2_image-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/webp.framework/webp: No se puede crear el enlace simbólico a «Versions/Current/webp»: Función no implementada
/usr/bin/tar: SDL2_image-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/webp.framework/Headers: No se puede crear el enlace simbólico a «Versions/Current/Headers»: Función no implementada
/usr/bin/tar: SDL2_image-2.0.4/Xcode/Frameworks/webp.framework/Versions/Current: No se puede crear el enlace simbólico a «A»: Función no implementada
/usr/bin/tar: Se sale con estado de fallo debido a errores anteriores
```

My computer is in spanish so I'll translate the spanish bits:

No se puede crear el enlace simbólico a «A»: Función no implementada > Can't create symbolic link «A»: Function not implemented

Se sale con estado de fallo debido a errores anteriores >
It comes with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: Do you have openjdk 8 installed? Also, the Kivy wheels are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue . The problem was that I was not using the correct java version. I was using jdk-11 ,but I had to use OpenJDK-8-jdk. Please check your java version with the command

```
java -version
```

That will show you the java version. Now when It doesn´t show "OpenJDK version 1.8.0_242" Consider installing it using

```
sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-8-jdk
```

When you want to switch through java versions. Use the command

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: I tried this solution but I still get an error. I'll edit my question

Comment: Hi ,as per your edit, we cant see the error. Note that it saying error is hidden above the log. So please show us the above log. Where a error will definitely been seen

Comment: U did nit actually posted a error. The error is hidden above the picture

Comment: I changed the log for the question. There are some things is spanish but I have translated them as best I could